# My Lex chatbot is not replying other people

Tags: facebook, integration, chatbot, amazon-lex

I created Lex chatbot and tried to configure it with the Facebook page. The bot is integrated completely, and also replying to me perfectly. The only reason I am facing is that my Lex bot doesn't reply when someone else tries to reach it.

In the start, I thought it was due to a status issue, but now I set my app's status to live but didn't get a response when I tried to text it through another account.

Comment: Did you submit your app for review?

Comment: Yeah i submitted app review that was the issue that i realized yesterday.